# Take screen shoot of client windows using php script

Tags: php, linux

Is this possible to take screenshots of windows's screen of client users using a `PHP` application?

Comment: The PHP script runs on the server. It completes before the page is displayed in the browser; the browser runs on a different computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the current *client web page*, you should look into JS solutions (see [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678156/7796750)):

- [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)
- npm packages with keyword [‘screenshot’](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/screenshot)

You may also be able to programatically load and render HTML with a GET request, though you will still need to run JavaScript to render the full web page on the server side.

If you mean a screenshot of the *actual desktop*, I fear only the browser would be able to do it and this is still at an experimental stage, probably due to security concerns:

- Chrome [desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) extension
- MDN [Media Capture and Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API)
- [Can I use `media capture`?](https://caniuse.com/#search=media%20capture)

---

**Edit**: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots). Some back-end libraries to render a web page:

- [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (PHP5)
- [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) (C++)