# Imagemagick : PHP Script giving 'import: unable to open X server'

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick

I am trying to capture my current window using ImageMagick using PHP script, but got error as response. I did searched for it in stackoverflow, but none of them solved my issue. I did installed imagemagick in my machine Ubuntu 14.04 . Following command gives me proper output.

```
import -window root screenshot.jpg
```

I have this in image.php

```
<?php
 exec( "/usr/bin/convert rose: -resize 200x200 output.jpg");
 exec( "/usr/bin/import -window root screenshot.jpg");
?>
<img src="output.jpg"/>
```

I have executed this from terminal

```
php image.php
```

And i got desired response(screen got captured and a file got created name screenshot.jpg)

Then i tried to access this above php script using my browser, The **convert** command works fine but for **import** comamnd nothing happens, i tried checking my apache log and it gives me following error

```
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.
```

What am i missing here?

Is it a permission issue?

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/757778/4175515

Comment: @JoaoVitorino . Thanks for the reference, but i want to know , how to resolve the error which i am getting in my apache log? . Any help on that?

Comment: Try run the commands with the apache user and post what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this only for tests and/or studies:

1 - Check if the apache user can run the commands

```
/usr/bin/convert rose: -resize 200x200 output.jpg
/usr/bin/import -window root screenshot.jpg
```

2 - Check if you have X11 installed and configured, set the display env var. DISPLAY=:0 for example

3 - Adjust the command import

/usr/bin/import -window *root*

to /usr/bin/import -window **apache_user**

or /usr/bin/import -window **your_user**

If you are trying to create a website that will be accessed by multiple clients with different operational systems, your code will not work. You will need to do that using only PHP code because, obviously, the windows machine does not have the convert and the import commands.

You can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757778/4175515) some how to's