# Converting text on webpage to image on load

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a webpage to image on load.

1) fetching data from MySQL database

2) Populating it on a webpage with bootstrap

3) want to show the entire page as one image on the screen.

I tried

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
```

but it says some error in the image. When I remove the header it shows no error.

I am sure something is missing here. 
I googled and SOed it but solutions are not working for me. 
Please help.

Comment: that's not that easy as it sounds, I'm afraid....

Comment: You can run a headless Chrome, take a screenshot, and stream that image to the browser: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots)

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya I have seen that solutions and that does not work for me. It takes a snap of screen and saves it in image file format. I want to convert the webpage to image temporarily.

Comment: So what's gonna render your web page into an image? Especially with fairly modern CSS? Answer: a browser.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen initially I tried to show it as pdf, but it does not take bootstrap into consideration. So now I have to generate temp image of the content and display on the browser.

Comment: HTML is just a language that browsers understand; if you want to render it (meaning things such as convert it to an image) you need a browser or browser-simulator in order to get such image, see the links the other comments posted here.