# Save urls screenshots with php

Tags: php, html, css, google-api, screenshot

I have some urls daily , and need capture screenshot from these URLs. 
I want to save specific urls screenShot in my Host.
Now I want to try it in localhost/wamp and also in linux host .

I try some libraries but weren`t successfully .
I want to try with google api pagespeed v5 .

```
<?php
$url = 'mysite.com';
$response =     file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=$url&screenshot=true");
$googlePagespeedObject = json_decode($response, true);
$screenshot = $googlePagespeedObject['screenshot']['data'];
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'), array('/','+'), $screenshot);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,{$screenshot}\"     alt=\"Screenshot\" />";
file_put_contents('...', base64_decode($screenshot));
```

my error without any successfully image :

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=mysite.com&screenshot=true):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots)

Comment: the method doesnt work so I posted :-)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started "If you're just trying out the PageSpeed Insights API, you don't need an API key. If you plan on using the API in an automated way and making multiple queries per second, you'll need an API key."

Comment: there's a problem with your connection or company proxy, try upload your file to hosting or server, it'll work.

and don't forget to add http or https to your
`$url = 'mysite.com';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i modified your code a bit, Try this code. working [example](http://bajukakilima.com/so.php), saved image [here](http://bajukakilima.com/tmp/bajukakilima.com.jpg)

```
function ScreenShotUrl($url){
  $link = $url ;
  $name = parse_url($link)['host'];
  $resp = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=$link&screenshot=true");
  $resp = json_decode($resp, true);
  $data = str_replace('_','/',$resp['lighthouseResult']['audits']['final-screenshot']['details']['data']);
  $data = str_replace('-','+',$data);
  echo '<img src="' . $data . '" />';
  $img = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data)); 
  file_put_contents('tmp/'.$name.'.jpg', $img);
} 
$url = 'http://bajukakilima.com'; 
ScreenShotUrl($url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a Function to use for php screenshot :

```
function ScreenShotUrl($url){
$link = $url ;
$name = parse_url($link)['host'];
$googlePagespeedData = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=$link&screenshot=true");
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode($googlePagespeedData, true);
$screenshot = base64_decode($googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data']);
$data = str_replace('_','/',$googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data']);
$data = str_replace('-','+',$data);
$decoded = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('images/screenshots/'.$name.'.jpg',$decoded);
$file_name = "$name.jpg";
}
```