# How can I take a screenshot of a page with GD?

Tags: php, screenshot, gd

I am trying to take a screenshot of a page using GD library but as a result Screen capture only returns a black image.

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
?>

<?php
header("Location:http://10.32.172.30:9080/RTOnline/b/p/115");
$img = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
?>
```

Comment: `imagegrabscreen()` captures the (desktop) screen of the computer on which PHP itself runs, not the HTML page being served by PHP to a client computer's browser.

Comment: You can open the web page in a browser on the computer which is running Php and then take a screenshot using GD. Also the imagegrabscreen function only works on windows

Comment: Setting HTTP headers suggests you aren't running PHP from the command-line but through a web server. In that case you're most likely using the same credentials as the web server and there's certainly no desktop session open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use a command line tool to take a screenshot of a webpage. You can run the tool within Php using shell_exec function. For example the [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) command line tool allows converting from html to pdf and other formats.

If the web page contains complex JavaScript or Ajax, then you can use a headless browser to take the screenshot. For example see: [Chrome Headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#screenshots). Also see the [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) script. It allows taking screenshots using JavaScript.

Also see this question: [Website screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots)